# Applying DataFrame with logic expression to another DataFrame (need Pandas wizards)

Tags: python, pandas, expression, signal-processing

I have a DataFrame `conditions` with a set of conditions that are used like an expression:

```
             indicator     logic    value
Discount  'ADR Premium'     '<'     -0.5
Premium   'ADR Premium'     '>'      0.5
```

Now I have a dataframe `indicators` with a set of values, in this case there is just one indicator `ADR Premium`:

```
                             ADR Premium
2015-04-20 15:30:00-04:00    -0.102270
2015-04-21 15:30:00-04:00     0.235315
2015-04-22 15:30:00-04:00    -0.323919
2015-04-23 15:30:00-04:00     0.546363
2015-04-24 15:30:00-04:00    -0.714143
2015-04-27 15:30:00-04:00    -0.153165
2015-04-28 15:30:00-04:00     0.878494
2015-04-29 15:30:00-04:00     0.993079
2015-04-30 15:30:00-04:00    -0.824815
2015-05-04 15:30:00-04:00     1.644784
2015-05-05 15:30:00-04:00    -0.254343
2015-05-06 15:30:00-04:00    -0.268981
2015-05-07 15:30:00-04:00     0.591411
2015-05-08 15:30:00-04:00    -0.588047
2015-05-11 15:30:00-04:00    -0.458143
2015-05-12 15:30:00-04:00     0.063643
2015-05-13 15:30:00-04:00    -0.051659
2015-05-14 15:30:00-04:00     1.474963
2015-05-15 15:30:00-04:00    -0.172429
2015-05-18 15:30:00-04:00     0.035558
```

What I am hoping to achieve, is to apply the logic of `conditions` to `indicators`in order to produce a new dataframe called `signals`. To give you an idea of what I'm looking for, see below. This looks only at the first condition in `conditions` and the fifth value in `indicator` (because it evaluates to True):

```
signals_list = []

conditions_index = 0
indicators_index = 4

if eval( str(indicators[conditions.ix[conditions_index].indicator][indicators_index]) + conditions.ix[conditions_index].log
ic + str(conditions.ix[conditions_index].value) ):

    signal = {'Time': indicators.ix[indicators_index].name,
              'Signal': conditions.ix[conditions_index].name}

    signals_list.append(signal)

signals = pd.DataFrame(signals_list)
signals.index = signals.Time
signals.drop('Time', 1)
```

This leaves me with `signals`:

```
                             Signal
Time
2015-04-24 15:30:00-04:00  'Discount'
```

I would like to do this for all conditions across applicable indicators in the most efficient, Pandas-ic method. Looking forward to ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell from the question but I think you just want to classify each entry in `indicators` with according to some set of conditions for that column. First I would initialise signals:

```
signals = pd.Series(index=indicators.index)
```

This will be a series of nans. For a give indicator name (ADR premium in this case), logic, value and classification you can do something like

```
bool_vector = indicators.eval(' '.join(indicator, logic, value))
signals[bool_vector] = classification
```

In the example given, this would translate to

```
bool_vector = indicators.eval('ADR Premium < -0.5) 
signals[bool_vector] = 'discount'
```

For the first row in `conditions` and would set all rows which satisfy the condition to 'discount'. You can do the same for each row. It's hard to tell from the example but if you have multiple columns you may want to have signals as a DataFrame. You can loop through `conditions` using

```
for classification, (indicator, logic, value) in conditions.iterrows():
```

For a fully vectorized solution you'll need to give a fuller example.